# Excel VBA - delete table names from Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which creates tables named the same: "TestingTable" in sheets of different 15 excel files.
This is for a weekly/monthly report which combines with a query load from folder those 15 sheets. I need the same name for tables to be able to load and combine them in a query.
When the user creates a new sheet in any of the files to produce the current report, the table name increments to "Testing table 1", "Testing Table2" etc. My excel query is based on the name "Testing table", so need to make sure the table name for the latest report doesn;t increment. I am thinking I need to add to my code, before the lines creating the table, a line to delete the table name from any sheet in the woorkbook. Tried the below deletion inserted in the code but didn't work. Any ideas?

```vb
Public Sub TestSub()
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim currentRange As Range
    Dim currentRange2 As Range
    Dim currentTable As TableObject
    Dim firstRow As Integer
    Dim columNumber As Integer
    Dim columnName As String
    ThisWorkbook.ListObjects("TestingTable").Delete
    ThisWorkbook.ListObjects("TestingTable3").Delete
        
    
    lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Current").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    firstRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Current").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    
    ' step 1 - find last row
        
    For columNumber = 1 To 1000
        columnName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Current").Cells(firstRow, columNumber)
        If columnName = "Current+3" Then
            GoTo Proceed
        End If
    Next columNumber
        
Proceed:
     
    'Set currentRange = shData.Range("A" & firstRow & ":S" & lastRow)
    
    Set currentRange2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Current").Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Current").Cells(firstRow, 1), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Current").Cells(lastRow, columNumber))
    

    'step 2- find first column
    
    
    ' assign range to a variable
    
    ' crate table from range variable
      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Current").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, currentRange2, , xlYes).Name = "TestingTable"
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access ListObjects collection from Workbook, as it is member of Worksheet object, so this part of your code would not work

```
ThisWorkbook.ListObjects("TestingTable").Delete
```

It should be rather `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName").ListObjects("TestingTable").Delete`

Comment: Thanks, I think i could iterate through all sheets of workbook and delete table names

Comment: Yeap. Also instead reffering to fixed table name like "TestingTable1", "TestingTable2", it is better to iterate trough ListObjects withing worksheet and if name is Like "TestingTable*" delete this object. This way you avoid multiplied lines of code.

Comment: Thanks, how can I enter in the code the instruction to perform actions based on name like %Testing etc?

Comment: If you loop trought ListObjects let say using for ... each loop.
`For each lstObj in wrkSheet.ListObjects
  If lstObj.Name Like "TestTable*" Then lstObj.Delete
Next lstObj`